# Different oauth callback URLs for Dev/Production?

Tags: meteor

I am wondering if it's possible to have separate configurations for GitHub/OAuth for development and production. I'm assuming this is baked it, but I can't find it.

I have a custom configuration that looks something like this:

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service:    "github",
  clientId:   "19c25aeb2a609872672d",
  secret:     "07136530fa20c3722caf6c2decc3776ca8729cf2"
});
```

It works like a dream locally, as the keys were set up for use with localhost. I tried specifying another for production (with no distinction between dev and production in the codebase, just another .insert()), like this:

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service:    "github",
  clientId:   "19c25aeb2a609872672d",
  secret:     "07136530fa20c3722caf6c2decc3776ca8729cf2"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service:    "github",
  clientId:   "9f9e82b7ab0a1e1f3ec1",
  secret:     "12c1ab66f2c5d37c8c55390d09725c400e1bca84"
});
```

When I deployed to production, it looks like it's going with the first configuration (localhost).

Answer (score 1):

On server startup (yes, this will be server code), clear **all** `Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration` entries. Then reinsert them according to use:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.find({}).remove();
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
        // Insert all login configs for development
    } else {
        // Insert all login configs for production
    }
}
```